# Nodejs - ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl, tls1.2

I have called this function below:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch("https://links.papareact.com/pyp");
  const exploreData = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      exploreData,
    },
  };
}
```

And it is showing the error below. How do I solve this issue?

[image]

```
Server Error
FetchError: request to https://jsonkeeper.com/b/4G1G failed, reason: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: jsonkeeper.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:www.jsonkeeper.com
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

Call Stack
ClientRequest.<anonymous>
file:///P:/Work/Web%20Development/airbnb-clone/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/node-fetch/index.js (1:65756)
ClientRequest.emit
node:events (527:28)
TLSSocket.socketErrorListener
node:_http_client (454:9)
TLSSocket.emit
node:events (527:28)
emitErrorNT
node:internal/streams/destroy (157:8)
emitErrorCloseNT
node:internal/streams/destroy (122:3)
processTicksAndRejections
node:internal/process/task_queues (83:21)`your text`
```

I was trying to call an API but its showing

```
type: 'system',
  errno: 'ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID',
  code: 'ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID',
```

I have installed mkcert but the problem was not solved.

Comment: You access the site with the name "jsonkeeper.com". The certificate is only valid for "www.jsonkeeper.com". That's why it complains that the certificate is not matching the name in the URL You either need to fix your certificate to also include  "jsonkeeper.com" or you need to fix the URL you access by not using plain " "jsonkeeper.com" but  "www.jsonkeeper.com" instead.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add www to the jsonkeeper link

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch('https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/4G1G');
  const exploreData = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      exploreData,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using NextJS my code required to send the "Host" header with the Domain which is registered in the certificate.
After it I was receiving an error for including the `https`, so i removed the https in the Host header and only leave the domain name (example.com) and it did the trick.